# Swift: Alamofire & URL Session Ephemeral Cookie Storage

Tags: swift, alamofire, swift5

I have declared an ephemeral session using the following operation:

```swift
var session = Alamofire.Session(configuration: URLSessionConfiguration.ephemeral)
```

I am looking to try and access the cookie storage of the session to both read and add cookies, I have seen similar solutions online for regular shared sessions but not any mention of using it for an ephemeral session.

Any solutions/help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be easily done by accessing the session's cookie store which will allow you to read and write cookies.

**Reading Cookies**

```swift
session.httpCookieStorage?.cookies
```

This will provide you with an array for all cookies in that current session.

**Writing Cookies**

```
let cookieProps = [
    HTTPCookiePropertyKey.domain: "example.com",
    HTTPCookiePropertyKey.path: "/",
    HTTPCookiePropertyKey.name: "COOKIE_KEY",
    HTTPCookiePropertyKey.value: "COOKIE_VALUE",
    HTTPCookiePropertyKey.secure: "TRUE",
  ]
if let newCookie = HTTPCookie(properties: cookieProps){
     session.httpCookieStorage?.setCookie(newCookie)
}
```

Here you can add the cookie/cookies as desired and they will be added to the session.

N.B. The process is the same for all sessions regardless of type.